# How can I find all connected objects of the same type recursively?

Tags: libgdx, box2d

In my game, when a user selects an object of some type, I'd like to search for all other objects of the *same* type that are connected to that first one.

For example, if the user selects a object of type 2, I want to check the object next to that one to see if it is also of type 2 and so on in all directions (up, down, left and right, et cetera) until there are no more objects of that type connected.

Does anyone know how I could do something like this? You can assume I have access to the set of connections from any given object.

Comment: Are the objects in a grid, or are they jumbled together using physics? If the user tilts the device do the move?  We need more details.

Comment: No the objects are in a grid using Physics. There is no rotation so all of the objects stay in place and only fall down if one object under it is removed.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include follow-up questions; instead, post a separate question. I have removed the follow-up.

Comment: Also, to the close-voters: I do not see what is unclear about this question at all. If you happened to vote to close (or if you didn't but do see something that needs improving), could you please explain what you find unclear about the question so it can be improved?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your objects are stored in a grid (2D or flattened 2D array ), you can use a flood fill like algorithm. Though it will be simpler, as you don't need all the problems and edge cases that come with image processing.

Start with the object that was selected by the user. Check the object to the right if it's the same type if it's not that will be the recursion termination case. Repeate the process for all neighbors. To track the object you can simply pass a vector by refecrence and add any new items (or their indices) to the list. Here is a psudo code:

```
func Floodfill ( int currentIdx, targetObjectType):
  If ( targetObjectType of node != objectType[currentIdx] )
     return;

  Add currentObject to list

  Floodfill (one step to the west of node, targetObjectType);
  Floodfill (one step to the east of node, targetObjectType);
  Floodfill (one step to the north of node, targetObjectType);
  Floodfill (one step to the south of node, targetObjectType);

  return;
```

Comment: I think this solution is the one i am looking for. I am going to try it out and see what happens. Thank you.

Comment: I am using this method but i keep getting a stack overflow error. I updated my code above.

Comment: @twalker22 it seems you have a large number of objects. You either need to implement the same (preferably) solution  in iterative approach or increase the size of your stack.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your objects are stored in a grid, but really it doesn't matter so long as you have a list of connections between any given object (which it certainly sounds like you do).

This is the kind of thing like lends itself to a recursive solution. In the most basic case, a click occurs on an object and you want to check all the connected objects, in C#-like pseudo-code (which should be easily translatable):

```
void GetConnectedObjects(Object object, List<Object> results) {
  // Consider the clicked object part of the results, always.
  results.Add(object);

  foreach(connection in object.Connections) {
    if (connection.TargetObject.Type == object.Type) {
      results.Add(connection.TargetObject);
    }
  }
}
```

This simply loops through all the connections of some object, checks their type, and if they match, adds the connected object to the result set (which also always contains the clicked object). You can replace the "connections" loop with a loop that checks adjacent grid X, Y positions if you are using a grid instead; the idea is the same.

Now the next step is to do this *exact same thing* for every connected object that matches. We can adjust the function as so:

```
void GetConnectedObjects(Object object, List<Object> results) {
  // Consider the clicked object part of the results, always.
  results.Add(object);

  foreach(connection in object.Connections) {
    if (connection.TargetObject.Type == object.Type) {
      // Note that we no longer need to explicitly add the target object
      // here, since the function always adds the first parameter to the
      // result set.
      GetConnectedObjects(connection.TargetObject, results);
    }
  }
}
```

This will find *all* connected objects, and might seem like the final solution.

But there is a caveat: consider a graph of connected objects like (`A -> B -> C -> A`) or, on a grid, a 2x2 block of objects of the same type. Because the above solution does not consider if an object has *already been seen*, it can recurse *forever* in such a case. So you need to track that:

```
void GetConnectedObjects(Object object, HashSet<Object> seen, List<Object> results) {
  results.Add(object);
  seen.Add(object);

  foreach(connection in object.Connections) {
    if (connection.TargetObject.Type == object.Type) {
      if (!seen.Contains(connection.TargetObject)) {
        // If we have already seen this connected object, don't
        // traverse it again.
        continue;
      }

      GetConnectedObjects(connection.TargetObject, results);
    }
  }
}
```

That should provide you a basic starting platform. Note that for API usability, I'd recommend making the above function a private implementation detail and instead exposing a cleaner public method:

```
List<Object> GetConnectedObjects(Object object) {
  List<Object> results = new List<Object>();
  HashSet<Object> seen = new HashSet<Object>();
  GetConnectedObjects(object, seen, results);

  return results;
}
```

Remember also that any recursive solution can be written as an iterative one, and iterative solutions can be better in some cases because they do not have stack recursion limits. Although I feel the problem is more naturally explained as a recursive solution, in practice I'd suggest trying your hand at converting it to an iterative one to avoid any limitations you can run into due to stack depth, et cetera. Remember also that the above was pseudocode meant to provide a basic idea of the algorithm and certainly could be more optimally constructed in your specific language